# line 475, in draw self.spritedict[spr] = surface_blit(spr.image, spr.rect)

Tags: python-3.x, pygame

```
import pygame
import random

WIDTH = 360
HEIGHT = 480
FPS = 30


WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)


pygame.init()
pygame.mixer.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([WIDTH, HEIGHT])
pygame.display.set_caption("My Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((10, 10))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.centerx = WIDTH / 2
        self.rect = HEIGHT - 10




all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
Player = Player()
all_sprites.add(Player)

running = True
while running:

    clock.tick(FPS)

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False


    all_sprites.update()


    screen.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Hello I am getting this error when i am trying to run this program  File , line 54, in 
    all_sprites.draw(screen)
   line 475, in draw
    self.spritedict[spr] = surface_blit(spr.image, spr.rect)
TypeError: invalid destination position for blit. Plz help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rect attribute must be an Rect object but you're overriding it with an integer in the line `self.rect = HEIGHT - 10`. Since a single integer isn't a valid location to blit a sprite on you get *"invalid destination position for blit"*.